# Uniformly convergence of the continuous functions sequence, $f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n, f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ with $A(\neq \phi) \subset \mathbb{R}$

Here the $f_n$ are the sequence of the continuous functions.

I already knew the fact "$f_n$ is uniformly converge to  $ f$ on $D$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous on $D$"

But There is a lecturer's claim that

Say $f_n$ is continuous on $A$

"$f_n$ is uniformly converge to  $ f$ on $A$ $\not\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous on $A$" **(statement (*))**

He suggested the counter-example as like the below.

$f_n, f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $A(\neq \phi) \subset \mathbb{R}$

Here the $D = \mathbb{R}, A = \mathbb{Q}^c$ and

Since the rational number set,$\mathbb{Q}$ is  countable so $\mathbb{Q} = \{x_1, x_2, .... \}$

Then Defining each functions like the below

$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}1  & \text{$x  \in  \{ x_1, x_2, ...,x_n\}$} \\
0 & \text{$o.w.$}\end{cases}$

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1  & \text{$x \in \mathbb{Q} $ } \\
0 & \text{$x \in \mathbb{Q}^c$}
\end{cases}$

From here, my question begins.

First question) I put in to the sequence $x_{n+1} \in \mathbb{Q}$ to $\Vert f_n(x) - f(x) \Vert$

Then  $\Vert f_n(x_{n+1}) - f(x_{n+1}) \Vert$ =  $\Vert 0-1 \Vert = 1 \geq \epsilon(= {1 \over 2}) $

So my conclusion is this counterexample is totally wrong, since $f_n$ is not uniformly converge to $f$. What do you think about that? Is my thought wrong?

Second question) Like the lecture's thought, I guess the **statement (*)** is false. But I can't find any counterexample. If the lecture's counterexample is false, Please give me a counterexample.

p.s.) If the statement is true, Why does the **statement(*)** hold?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no connection between $D$ and $A$ in $(*)$. So $(*)$ is correct. For one example take $D=[0, \frac  12 ], A=[0,1]$, $f_n(x)=x^{n}, f(x)=0$ for  $ x<1$, $f(1)=1$. Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $D$ and $f$ is not continuous on $A$.

However, the example given by the lecturer is wrong since $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on $D=\mathbb R$.

Answer for the revised question: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $A$ and each $f_n$ is continuous on $A$ then the restriction of  $f$  to $A$ is continuous. But you cannot say that $f$ is continuous at points of $A$ as in the example by your lecturer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Dear Mr,@Murthy. But I should have been asked "$f_n$ is uniformly converge to  $ f$ on $A$" in statement (*) not "$f_n$ is uniformly converge to  $ f$ on $D$" Sorry for typo. I edited my question.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you. :)

Comment: What about the case if we add the condition $A \subset D$? Though adding more condition, his claim and counterexample are still not hold, right?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang Actually $f_n(x)=f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $A$ in his example. So $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $A$.

Comment: Then, when we add the condition "$A \subset D$" at the statement (*), his counter-example is reasonable. So, lecturer's claim is true, right? I'm very confused because $f_n \to f$ is uniformly on $A$ then $f$ should be continuous on $A$.(Because $f_n $is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}^c$) But, $f$ is not continuous on $A$. So its result is contradict with the fact that uniform convergence property(preservation of the continuity)

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I have dited  my answer to clear the doubts.

Comment: Dear Mr.@Murthy, Yes, I've totally agreed your answer that $f$ is not continuous on $A$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $A$. But my key point was ,at least I thought, $f_n$ is continuous on $A$, hence $f$ should be continuous. But As we knew it is contradict with the $f$ is discontinuous on $A$. So it is contradict with the preservation of the continuity in uniformly convergence which is clear and well known thm. So the key point was this makes me confused.(I couldn't find which point I was wrong)

Comment: @se-hyuckyang When you consider $A$ a s a metric space in its own right you can say that $f$ is continuous on $A$ becasue it is a uniform limit of continuous functions. But this only means that If $a_n \to a$ with $a_n,a \in A$ then $f(a_n) \to a$. If you take  sequence $(a_n)$ not contained in $A$ but converging to a point of $a$ of $A$ you cannot say that $f(a_n) \to f(a)$. So we cannot say that $f$ is continuous at points of $A$ when $f$ is considered as a function with domain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yeah, The cause of the sticking point was domain of the functions. You saved my life again!